# Why does my python text search work correctly for some rows in my csv file but not for others?

Tags: python, text, unicode, text-mining

I wrote a python script that opens and reads a CSV file that has the following structure

```
ID|Search Company|Past Job Title 1|Past Job Title 2|Past Job Title 3|
```

It then writes a CSV file with the following structure

```
ID|Search Company|Consolidated Company| Past Job Title 1|Past Job Title 2|Past Job Title 3|
```

I also have the following python code

```
input_filename = 'filename.csv'

input_headers = ['ID',
                 'Search Company',
                 'Past Job Title 1',
                 'Past Job Title 2',
                 'Past Job Title 3']

output_headers = ['ID',
                 'Search Company',
                 'Consolidated Company',
                 'Past Job Title 1',
                 'Past Job Title 2',
                 'Past Job Title 3']



#set up the file writer
out_employees_file = open('consolidated_' + input_filename, 'wb')
employees_writer = unicodecsv.DictWriter(out_employees_file, 
lineterminator='\n', escapechar='\\', fieldnames=output_headers)

#set up the file reader
employees_file = open(input_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
employees_reader = csv.reader(employees_file, delimiter=',')


for row in employees_reader:
    consolidated_name = ''
    if 'Searched Company' != row[1]:
        if row[1] in row[2]:
            consolidated_name = row[2]

        if row[1] in row[3]:
            consolidated_name = row[3]

        if row[1] in row[4]:
            harmonized_name = row[4]

    employees_writer.writerow({'ID': row[0],
                           'Consolidated Company':consolidated_name,
                           'Past Job Title 1':row[2],
                           'Past Job Title 2':row[3],
                           'Past Job Title 3':row[4]})
employees_file.flush()
employees_file.close()
```

My script runs, the problem is that it only behaves like expected when reading certain lines of a CSV file. For some reason Python is only able to find the company name that I'm looking for in some of the rows of the CSV file.

I'll give a sample input file.

```
ID|Search Company|Past Job Title 1|Past Job Title 2|Past Job Title 3|
 1|Good Company  |Bad Company     | Horrid Cmp LLC |Good Company    |
 2|Good Company  |Good Company    | Rotten Company |Stupid Company  |
 3|Good Company  |Stinky Company  | Good Company   |Company Malo    |
```

This is the output that I'm getting

```
ID|Search Company|Consolidated Company|Past Job Title 1|Past Job Title 2|Past Job Title 3|
 1|Good Company  |                    |Bad Company     | Horrid Cmp LLC |Good Company    |
 2|Good Company  |Good Company        |Good Company    | Rotten Company |Stupid Company  |
 3|Good Company  |                    |Stinky Company  | Good Company   |Company Malo    |
```

I should be getting a value in the Consolidated Company column for every row of the output file since 'Good Company' shows up in every row of the file. However, what I'm actually seeing is that I'm only getting a value in some of the rows.

I haven't been able to figure out why my script works for some of the rows of my input file but fails for other rows of my input file. I would think that my script would either work for everything or fail for everything but it doesn't, why is that?

Comment: one is that you use 'consolidated_company' for the first two, and then 'harmonized_company' for the last one... so if it would match row[4], it assigns the wrong variable and won't be seen...

Comment: The call to `employees_writer.writerow()` needs to be inside the `for` loop. Otherwise you'll only write the last row.

Comment: If you want to skip the header line, use `employees_reader.next()` before the loop, rather than testing the contents every time. The test is also wrong: `'Searched Company'` should be `'Search Company'`

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Could there be some other reason? That is a typo that was introduced when I was editing things for StackOverflow. The actual file has about 30 different fields, but it didn't make sense to put them all in my post. Assume that the last harmonized name is the same as the first two.

Comment: @Barmar The issue with the for loop was introduced when I typed everything into StackOverflow. In the actual file, the write command is inside of the foor loop.

Comment: It's better to just paste the original code, and use Ctl-k to mark it as code, then the indentation should be kept. Also, you won't introduce typos that are different from the original. Is the `harmonized_company` variable name in the original code or a copying error?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and it works:

```
import csv
import unicodecsv

input_filename = 'test.csv'

input_headers = ['ID',
                 'Search Company',
                 'Past Job Title 1',
                 'Past Job Title 2',
                 'Past Job Title 3']

output_headers = ['ID',
                  'Search Company',
                  'Consolidated Company',
                  'Past Job Title 1',
                  'Past Job Title 2',
                  'Past Job Title 3']

#set up the file writer
out_employees_file = open('consolidated_' + input_filename, 'wb')
employees_writer = unicodecsv.DictWriter(out_employees_file,
lineterminator='\n', escapechar='\\', fieldnames=output_headers)

#set up the file reader
employees_file = open(input_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
employees_reader = csv.reader(employees_file, delimiter=',')

rows = []

for row in employees_reader:
    consolidated_name = ''
    if 'Search Company' != row[1]:
        if row[1] in row[2]:
            consolidated_name = row[2]

        if row[1] in row[3]:
            consolidated_name = row[3]

        if row[1] in row[4]:
            consolidated_name = row[4]
        r = {'ID': row[0],
             'Search Company': row[1],
             'Consolidated Company': consolidated_name,
             'Past Job Title 1': row[2],
             'Past Job Title 2': row[3],
             'Past Job Title 3': row[4]}
        rows.append(r)
employees_writer.writerows(rows)
```

You did not wrote the second row in your version (Searched company) and you had at least a type in the if condition:

```
if 'Searched Company' != row[1]:
```

But the row is called 'Search Company'. You missed the "ed".

I think, that was the main reason for your problem. Also you should collect the rows and write them with .writerows().

My Output:

```
1,Good Company,Good Company,Bad Company,Horrid Cmp LLC,Good Company
2,Good Company,Good Company,Good Company,Rotten Company,Stupid Compny
3,Good Company,Good Company,Stinky Company,Good Company,Company Malo
```

I discarded the headers, I know...

Edit: To include the headers, add

```
employees_writer.writer.writerow(output_headers)
```

just before

```
employees_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Could there be something else that makes things fail? I tried making the few changes that you made and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: hm.. Did you tried to run my version? I tried it again (copied it from my answer) and it still works.. I really think you have some semantically errors in your version. Please adjust the indentation of "employees_writer.writerow({'ID': row[0],...", fix the type in the if condition and double check if you have harmonized_name replaced with the right variable name (consolidated_name). Or simply copy my version to verify you have not missed something during your code changes..